# Upgrading from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5 with Ivy(not Gradle or Maven)

Tags: junit, junit4, ivy, junit5

I'm trying to update a legacy application that uses Ivy for dependency management from JUnit 4.12 to JUnit 5 and haven't found anything that doesn't rely on Gradle or Maven. Because of our non-standard, byzantine build/deploy process, I can't use one of those tools yet (we're working on it), currently I have:

```
<dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.12"/>
```

I've tried:

```
<dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="5.2.0"/>
<dependency org="junit5" name="junit5" rev="5.2.0"/>
<dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="5.1.0"/>
```

and a few similar things.

Has anyone been able to update to JUnit 5 using Ivy or are we just stuck with 4 until we get with the program and switch to Gradle/Maven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JUnit 5 is modularized (see [User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#dependency-metadata)).

You need at least `junit-jupiter-api` to compile your tests:

```
<dependency org="org.junit" name="junit-jupiter-api" rev="5.2.0"/>
```

Comment: thanks Marc, I later found that in the docs, you got your answer in before I could answer my own question :D